# How to iterate through a matrix using lists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, indexing

I am making a matrix in Python using lists. I hav Two words; s and t. I'm supposed to make a 'frame' with the numbers 0-len(word) as row and column and inside check if the letters of the words match or not. If yes, I have to enter the number that is at location row-1 and column - 1 (so top left side in the matrix). If it is not a match, I have to take the smallest of the three surrounding numbers and add 1 and put it in that location.

I managed to make the frame and check for matches, but I don't know how to 'reach' the top left number and the three surrounding numbers. So right now I just have 0 for match and 8 for not match. Can you tell how to put the right numbers in the spots? Thanks!

edit for clarification:
For example, in location I[1][1], I compare s[0] and t[0].
If they are the same, I put the number at location I[0][0] there. So top left number of that location, which is 0.

If they are not the same, I compare the number at location I[0][0] with the two numbers right and bottom, take the smallest number, add 1, and put it in location I[1][1].

Then I iterate through the matrix in this way until it is full.

```
I=[]
s = 'abcd'
t = 'abdd'

n = len(s)+1
m = len(t)+1

for row in range(n):
    new_row= list()
    for column in range(m):
        if row==0:
            new_row.append(column)    
        elif column ==0:
            new_row.append(row)      
        elif s[row-1]==t[column-1]:      
            new_row.append(0)        
        elif s[row-1]!=t[column-1]:
            new_row.append(8)       

    I.append(new_row)

print(I)
```

Comment: I dont understand what you expect the end result to look like with your example s and t strings

Comment: Have you looked into using numpy?

Comment: I added some clarification in the top OP

Comment: but at location [1][1] you havent put any value in [1][2] or [2][1] or [2][2]  you only have a value at locations `[1][0]`,`[0][0]`,and `[0][1]` so how do you take the minimum value considering half of the positions do not have a value yet?